# Angularjs: Complex table using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this scope variable:

```
$scope.item = {
    "main1": {
        "proj1": ["comp1", "comp2"],
        "proj2": ["comp3", "comp4", "comp5"]
    },
    "main2": {
        "proj3": ["comp1", "comp2"],
        "proj4": ["comp3", "comp4"],
        "proj5": ["comp1"]
    }
};
```

And I want the table like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/DWgLUeie3XzNYGx7RxcX?p=preview

I'm able to use the ng-repeat on the first column, but not sure on how to use it for other columns.

Comment: You should not to use `ngRepeat` here, writing other directive can be simpler.

Comment: @vp_arth: Found a solution from another post and marked this question as duplicate. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just be warned - all will too hard if you will want more levels/columns with this way :)

Comment: Agree you, I'm ensuring that I don't need more levels than this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the html is **not** correct below but you can unpack your json by following this pattern

```
 <... ng-repeat="(k1, v1) in item" ...>
    {{key}}    // main1
    <... ng-repeat="(k2,v2) in v1" ...>
        {{k2}}     // proj1
       <... ng-repeat="v3 in v2"...>
            {{v3}}     // comp1, comp2
```

Comment: This is the problem that I face. We have to think about rowspans for proj and comp columns. That is where I'm stuck. It would be great if you can try on the real table.

Comment: Use can use e.g. `rowspan={{v2.length}}`